# POST using SpringTemplate between 2 different projects

Tags: spring, web-services, rest, post, resttemplate

I'm working on an application that manages professor's reservations, and it's supposed to use different functionalities in other projects using WebServices.
 I have a RestController that i made in Project Called WSSpring and
this is it's code.

```
package org.icda.entry;
import java.util.List;
import org.icda.entry.entities.Professor;
import org.icda.entry.professor.metier.IProfessorMetier;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/Profs")
public class ProfessorController {

@Autowired
private IProfessorMetier professorMetier;

@RequestMapping(value = "/sortProfs", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Professor> sortPorfessors() {
    return professorMetier.sortPorfessors();
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/allProfs", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Professor> listAllProfessors() {
    return professorMetier.listAllProfessors();
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/findProf/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Professor findOne(@PathVariable Long id) {
    return professorMetier.findOne(id);
}

 @RequestMapping(value = "/saveProf", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public Professor save(@RequestBody Professor p) {
    return professorMetier.save(p);
 }
}
```

Now i had to make my client application that exists in an other project called WSSpringClient to communicate with the RestController. 
I developed a solution based on RestTemplate.
This is how my client class looks like.

```
package org.icda.client.metier;

import java.net.URI;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

public class ProfessorClient implements IProfessorClient {

public static final String REST_SERVICE_URI = "http://localhost:8080 /entry/Profs";

public static void main(String[] args) {
  ProfessorClient professor = new ProfessorClient();
  professor.listAllProfessors();
  System.out.println("Sorting .....");
  professor.sortPorfessors();
  Object object = professor.findOne(2L);
  System.out.println(object.toString());
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public List<Object> listAllProfessors() {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    List<Object> objects = restTemplate.getForObject(REST_SERVICE_URI
            + "/allProfs", List.class);
    for (Object o : objects) {
        System.out.println(o.toString());
    }
    return objects;
}

@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked" })
@Override
public List<Object> sortPorfessors() {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    List<Object> objects = restTemplate.getForObject(REST_SERVICE_URI
            + "/sortProfs", List.class);
    for (Object o : objects) {
        System.out.println(o.toString());
    }
    return objects;
}

@Override
public Object findOne(Long id) {
    Map<String, Long> profsMap = new HashMap<String, Long>();
    profsMap.put("id", id);
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    Object object = restTemplate.getForObject(REST_SERVICE_URI
            + "/findProf/{id}", Object.class, profsMap);
    System.out.println("Searching for user number....."+id);
    return object;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
@Override
public Object save(Object p) {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    URI uri = restTemplate.postForLocation(REST_SERVICE_URI + "/saveProf",p, Object.class);
    return p;
}
}
```

My problem is that i don't know how to POST a professor Object is 
RestTemplate as u can see in the last method.

If you have any suggestion guys, thanks for sharing it.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your `/saveProf` endpoint can accept `JSON` or `XML` representations of `Professor`. So, you will send a, say `JSON`, representation of `Professor` in your `POST` call and then `save` handler method would read your HTTP message body using its registered `HttpMessageConverter` and populates the `Professor` object.

Let's say that you're gonna send this `JSON`:

```
{
    "name": "someone",
    "degree": "PhD"
}
```

You should write something like this in your client:

```
// Prepare professor representation
Map<String, Object> professor = new HashMap<>();
professor.put("name", "someone");
professor.put("degree", "PhD");

// Prepare request
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json");
HttpEntity<Map<String, Object>> request = new HttpEntity<>(professor, headers);

// Send prepared request
ResponseEntity<String> response = template.postForEntity(REST_SERVICE_URI + "/saveProf", request, String.class);
```